# How to combine 2 publishers and erase values to Void?

Tags: swift, combine

I have 2 publishers where I want to perform an action based on either response. I don't care about the values. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var hasChangedPublisher: AnyPublisher<(Void, Void), Never> {
    Publishers.CombineLatest(
        preferences.publisher,
        state.$permissionStatus
    ).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

If `preferences.publisher` fires first but not the other, I want to fire. If `state.$permissionStatus` fires but not the other, I want to fire. I don't really want to `CombineLatest`, but not sure how to fire if either emit.

Is there a way to produce an even if either fire but more elegantly erase its values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `Merge` instead of `CombineLatest`. Your code for this would look a bit like the following:

```
var hasChangedPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
  preferences.publisher
    .merge(state.$permissionStatus)
    .map({ _ in
      return () // transform to Void
    })
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Since there had unrelated outputs, I had to do something like this: preferences.publisher.map { _ in () }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .merge(with: state.$permissionStatus.catch { _ in Just(false) }.map { _ in () }.eraseToAnyPublisher())
    .eraseToAnyPublisher(). Is there a more condensed version to do this??

Comment: You can drop most of your eraseToAnyPublisher() calls. Those are only useful to "hide" internal publishers when exposing them to anther part of your code. In this case you could write something like `preferences.publisher.map { _ in () }.merge(with: state.$permissionStatus.replaceError(true).map { _ in () }).eraseToAnyPublisher()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CombineLatest, use Merge.

CombineLatest creates a tuple based on all the publishers that are combined. It is great, except, it will not fire at all until every one of the combined publishers has fired at least once. After that, it will fire once for every firing of any of its combined publishers - (merging the last value from each publisher into the tuple).

Merge, instead, just multiplexes all combined publishers together and generates a stream of events - containing a stream of single values from any of the combined publishers.

Answer (score 1):

// transform to Void
.map { _ in }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).